# Trying to understand how Angular v4.4 actually works with platformBrowserDynamic and PlatformRef

Tags: angular, typescript

I have inherited an Angular 4.4 application using Webpack v3.5 and TypeScript v2.3.3. I have been struggling to understand what the code I see (imported) is actually doing and part of it is I don't understand how it can even be correct. Note, I have performed some simplification in the following code to make it easier to focus on the question.

My main.ts contains these statements (among others):

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic }  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic;'
return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then...;
```

​
So, platformBrowserDynamic is a function which is invoked there. Meanwhile, in @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.d.ts is this statement

```js
export * from './src/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

In @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.d.ts are these statements:

```js
import { PlatformRef, Provider } from '@angular/core';
export declare const platformBrowserDynamic: (extraProviders?: Provider[] | undefined) => PlatformRef;
```

In other words, platformBrowserDynamic is a function returning whatever PlatformRef is. In @angular/core/core.d.ts is this export:

```js
export * from './public_api';
```

In @angular/core/public_api.d.ts is

```js
export * from './src/core';
```

In @angular/core/src/core.d.ts is

```js
export { createPlatform, assertPlatform, destroyPlatform, getPlatform, PlatformRef, ApplicationRef, enableProdMode, isDevMode, createPlatformFactory, NgProbeToken } from './application_ref';
```

So, that is where the definition of PlatformRef is coming from. In @angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts, are these statements:

```js
export declare abstract class PlatformRef { 
   abstract bootstrapModuleFactory<M>(
...
}

export declare class PlatformRef_ extends PlatformRef { ... }
```

PlatformRef is defined as an abstract base class. Now, PlatformRef_ (with underscore appended) is defined as a "concrete" class, but that class name is not referenced. BUT, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes says:

> Abstract classes are base classes from which other classes may be derived.
>   They may not be instantiated directly.

So WHAT is the call to platformBrowserDynamic() actually returning? An ABC? Or, an invocation of an ABC, which can't happen, according to the docs? And, if an ABC, then the story is even worse, as the reference to platformBrowserDynamic actually immediately calls an abstract method of that ABC, which is, of course, undefined. And, for sure, it is a working application, but I don't know how it could work.

Comment: you're a little caught in the weeds here... if you're developing an angular application, you have very little reason to be aware of angular internals like this.  the main.ts code is just bootstrapping the application. you'd be better served just going through the angular tutorial if you're brand new to the framework.

Comment: this is basically all you need to know about platform: https://angular.io/guide/glossary#platform and all you need to know about bootstrapping: https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping ... short version is that platformBrowserDynamic is just defining the context the application is running in so that the app can be bootstrapped (started / launched) correctly.. the purpose of it is to make angular more portable between platforms ... but i stress, angular's goal is to abstract all of this away so you don't need to be concerned with it. this is all boilerplate stuff.

Comment: I edited the question to further detail where the definitions of platformBrowserDynamic and PlatformRef are coming from. platformBrowserDynamic is not from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.js, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wanted to comment this but it's getting long....

you've got a couple fundamental misunderstandings of typescript and how it works in relation to javascript, and js package distribution in general.

first.. `.d.ts` extension files are only type declaration files for the benefit of the typescript transpiler. they don't have any actual runnable code, they just tell the transpiler what type functions and variables etc are.. they're (optionally) generated by the transpiler when you bundle your code for distribution, or sometimes maintained separately for libraries that aren't natively TS for TS compatibility purposes. You could put a `my-function.d.ts` file in your app root right now with the following:

```
declare function myFunction(a: string): string;
```

and typescript will happily take your word that `myFunction` exists and will let you run it anywhere in your project and tell you the typings for it, even though you haven't actually implemented it, and doing so will throw runtime errors. Because sometimes js libraries are loaded in a way that typescript can't know about, and this is how you tell it they're there. It's also how you tell it the typings for previously bundled packages you got from npm that are now in JS. more about declaration files: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

the `package.json` in angular core is pointing to an actual js file that has the real transpiled source code that webpack will grab and use in your bundled package, but it's barely human readable as it's generated code from typescript and webpack. the stuff you get from npm is not the source code you should be looking at to figure out angular's inner workings as npm generally delivers bundled packages for efficiency, along with type declaration files for the benefit of typescript users. to find the non transpiled / bundled typescript source, you should visit the angular github (https://github.com/angular/angular). it's all open source, and you can clone the repo and explore as much as you'd like, but you're trying to do the javascript equivalent of reading binaries or packages from nuget right now.

second... when it says the return type is `PlatformRef` which is an abstract class, it doesn't mean it's returning an instance of `PlatformRef`, it means it's returning an instance of a class that extends or implements `PlatformRef`.  It could be any number of different concrete implementations of `PlatformRef`.  This is useful because it allows developers to have different platform refs for different platforms, like browser vs mobile app, so the data and event bindings can be abstracted away and swapped out at the lowest level.  This makes angular code extremely portable. It also means that most angular developers don't have to worry about the particular implementation of `PlatformRef` while they're coding their app. They just need to know how to use the tools angular provides to create a portable application, as it's all been well abstracted away to let app developers focus on the app rather than the idiosyncrasies of browsers and mobile platforms.

I'll reiterate my point from my comments here, `PlatformRef` is just defining the application context so that angular can bind events and data correctly.  It needs to know if it's running in a browser or a mobile context so it can hook into button clicks or scrolls or gestures or whatever using the correct methods for the context while providing a consistent API for the developer.  It's just an abstraction so you as the developer can always bind to a click event with `<button (click)="myFunction()">` without ever worrying about the application context. I've personally gotten pretty deep into angular source over nearly a decade of working with it, and the information has been useful to me maybe a handful of times in very far edge scenarios. Angular source is really large and complex as it does a whole lot.  It's not a good starting point for angular, the countless development guides and tutorials are, and then get into the source later if you're still interested.

You'd need to know more about it if, lets say you were hoping to make your application work in like a smart tv/fridge/toaster/whatever. Then you would very much need to write your own concrete implementation of `PlatformRef` and write a factory function to deliver it.

Comment: Oh, I guess I was quite off track. I see the package.json references a bundle for main. And that bundle looks very different than the other code. And, I see it gets a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: When I first went looking for a description of what platformBrowserDynamic did, I did a search on the Angular website which led to https://angular.io/api/platform-browser-dynamic/platformBrowserDynamic . That set my expectations from there on. I found the same thing in my older Angular version, so I thought I was confirmed in my (mis)-understanding. I wish there was better documentation if something is so complex that you just want me to ignore the insides like a black box. I didn't find anything that said this is what that function does and what you use it for.

Comment: Anyway, in the best apologetic tradition of Gilda Rather, https://youtu.be/2g5vPDAeqm8?t=57 . Thanks for your help.

Comment: the docs are app developer centric rather than platform developer centric as the primary use case for the docs is helping to make applications.  But yes, the inner workings of the platform is very poorly documented and takes a lot of time to get through as a result.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the angular 4.4 [source code for platform-browser-dynamic](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.ts), you'll see the following

```
export const platformBrowserDynamic = createPlatformFactory(
    platformCoreDynamic, 'browserDynamic', INTERNAL_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS);
```

So `platformBrowserDynamic` is the function invocation of `createPlatformFactory`, that is to say it will be an instance of a factory class.

A factory class is used to instantiate object without necessarily knowing which actual class will be used, or when creating an object is a bit of work (like creating a component in angular for instance).

In this example, invoking the `platformBrowserDynamic` function/factory instantiate a child class extending `PlatformRef`, not an instance of the `PlatformRef` class itself (since it is abstract, like you pointed out)

However, like bryan60 said in the comments, you do not need to worry about all that stuff

**Edit**

I've digged a little deeper to answer your question regarding where the actual instance is created.

The child class extending the `PlatformRef` class is called `PlatformRef_` and is defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L259).

You can see that it implements all the necessary methods from the abstract parent class.

Note that you will not find any instance of `new PlatformRef_()`. `PlatformRef_` class is marked as `@Injectable` and will be eventually created with angular's injector. For that, it needs to be defined in the providers, which is done [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/platform_core_providers.ts#L24) for the core platform. Other platforms include browser, server and web worker.

The method which will eventually instantiate a new platform based on the providers is the method returned by [createPlatformFactory](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L101)

As to "how come a factory function programmed to return an abstract class can return a child class extending that class", this is part of the principles of object oriented programming (abstraction, inheritance and polymorphism). `PlatformRef` is a contract, you don't have to care about the implementation. It just means that the factory will return something that implements `PlatformRef`. Maybe it would have bean clearer to you if it was returning an interface, then abstract and implementation classes would remain hidden?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @David. I still don't how calling a factory function which is programmed to return an abstract class actually returns a "child class extended PlatformRef". Where is the code that creates the child class? Where is the definition of the abstract method that is included in the abstract class?

Comment: It may be the case that I don't need to understand how this works in order to use Angular, though I have found it quite challenging to try to understand this application I have inherited. I prefer to understand how things work. I think that is something a developer should do. And, if there is some magic to Angular, that is outside of the specified behavior for TypeScript/JavaScript, then I want to know that.

Comment: I have already become less than a fan of the Angular code I have seen because it is not designed to be clear and understandable. I don't know if the Angular developers were just hacks or they were trying to show off their cleverness. Either way, it doesn't leave a good feeling. But, maybe I'm completely off track here and I just am missing something basic that makes the referenced Angular code work with in the realm of language specifications.

Comment: I've update my answer, hope this helps you understand better

Comment: David, thanks for your further references. I now see your answer depends on "export const platformBrowserDynamic = createPlatformFactory" being in the code that is imported. I don't see that in the trace of the code imported. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Could the problem be that you are looking at your node module instead of the real source code?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start this answer specifying, as others said in comments, that this is not necessary at all in order to understand Angular basics and to get it working. That said, I understand the passion to dig inside libraries sources and trying to grasp their *"magic"*, so I'll try to explain it the better I can.

First, an abstract class is useful *exactly* for the purpouse it is used right here. An abstract class is, essentially, a *contract* (like an Interface, but potentially containing some core implementations usable by the *Inheriting child classes*).

Given this contract, Angular is making the promise to create and return to you an *instance* of a `PlatformRef`. As the name says, this is something that may differ given the platform you're on, quoting the docs (emphasis mine):

> In Angular terminology, a platform is the context in which an Angular application runs. The most common platform for Angular applications is a web browser, but *it can also be an operating system for a mobile device, or a web server*

Angular is not saying that it will return to you an instance of the *abstract class*. It is saying that it will give you an instance of **a class that respects the `PlatformRef` contract**. You don't need to know which it is, and you can use the `PlatformRef` methods in the contract without worrying, because it's Angular responsability to check the platform and provide you the **right implementation of `PlatformRef`, given the platform you're on**.

On the other side, if you think about the Angular devs point of view, they needed to give you some methods that can work in *every platform*. When you are installing Angular, **you** are their customer, and the Abstract Class is their **contract** with you. Or, simply, an Angular dev himself needs this contract in order to implement *other Angular features* without worrying about the platform.

In the source, you've seen:

```
export const platformBrowserDynamic = createPlatformFactory(
    platformCoreDynamic, 'browserDynamic', INTERNAL_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS)
```

This means that there are some internally registered *providers*, and the `createPlatformFactory` (a function that returns a factory function) is responsible for `PlatformRef` contract instancing. To give you an extremely simplified example of how this could work, let's think about this:

```
function createPlatform(): PlatformRef {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { // I'm clearly joking here..
    return new BrowserPlatformRef();
  } 
  // ..
}

class BrowserPlatformRef extends PlatformRef { /* ... */ }
```

As you said, `PlatformRef` by itself is *not* instantiable, meaning that `createPlatform` is **forced** to return a *child class deriving from `PlatformRef`*, since `new PlatformRef()` is not allowed.

Comment: leonardfactory - thanks for your efforts put into your answer. However, your answer depends on "export const platformBrowserDynamic = createPlatformFactory" being in the code that is imported. I don't see that in the trace of the code imported. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: You know, bryan60 finally was able to show me the problem in my understanding. Thanks for your help along the way!